# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Passport

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

This question has been asked before but was unable to solve anything with the previous listings.

I'm trying to authenticate using passport-cas and I'm running into an error that I don't really know a way around.

I believe the issue lies in the bottom code:

```
user.save((err) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    return done(null, user);
  });
```

particularly the done(null, user) which causes the error the first time a user tries to register.

**Problem:**

If the user clicks the login button twice then it logins in perfect. The reason for this is because it throws an ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error the first time, then redirects home. The second time, as said before works perfectly because the user is already in the database and does not need to be created.

**Any help on this would be amazing, my code is below:**

passport.js:

```
passport.use(new(require('passport-cas').Strategy)({
  ssoBaseURL: 'https://domain.edu/cas',
  serverBaseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
}, function(netid, done) {
  User.findOne({
    netid: netid
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      const user = new User({
        netid: netid
      });

      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
}));
```

user.js:

```
exports.casLogin = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('cas', function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

app.js:

```
const userController = require('./controllers/user');
app.get('/cas', userController.casLogin);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your `done()` callback twice in this code:

```
passport.use(new(require('passport-cas').Strategy)({
  ssoBaseURL: 'https://domain.edu/cas',
  serverBaseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
}, function(netid, done) {
  User.findOne({
    netid: netid
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      const user = new User({
        netid: netid
      });

      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        return done(null, user);             // calling it again here
      });
    }
    return done(null, user);                 // calling it first here
  });
}));
```

The issue is that the callback you pass to `user.save()` is called asynchronously and the `return` in there doesn't return from the parent function.  So, execution of the parent function continues and the `return done(null, user)` is called when you don't want it to be.

You can fix it by adding another `return`.

```
passport.use(new(require('passport-cas').Strategy)({
  ssoBaseURL: 'https://domain.edu/cas',
  serverBaseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
}, function(netid, done) {
  User.findOne({
    netid: netid
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      const user = new User({
        netid: netid
      });

      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        return done(null, user);
      });
      return;                            // <=== add this return
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
}));
```

You could also make the `if (!user)` into an `if/else` instead of adding the above `return`.